# How can I get values dynamically from SQL Server to .NET Framework web project?

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, synchronized

I am a newbie coder. I am building a website and need some help. I will try to explain what I need.

1. I have a table named `tbl_Orders` in SQL Server
2. And this is my `ViewBag` in the controller side of .NET Framework

   ```
   ViewBag.count = db.tbl_Oders.ToList().Count;
   ```

I can reach the count of orders in the table without any problem and can print the count to the label, but what I need is to print count of orders to the label dynamically while getting a new order  without refreshing the web page. It will work like a twitter notification, like to notice a notification dot that show how many new notification I have without refreshing the page. I hope this was a clean explanation. Any help will be welcomed. Sorry for my English and kind regards.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.count = db.tbl_Orders.ToList().Count;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
   label>@ViewBag.count</label
```

I need to see synchronized count in the label without refreshing webpage.

Comment: FYI `.ToList().Count` will `select * ...` and load the entire table into memory. `.Count()` will `select count(*) ...`.

Comment: Your actual question is too broad. If you want to change html without reloading, you need to look into javascript / ajax etc.